# When I move a Wordpress custom option menu to the top level it stop saving input settings?

Tags: wordpress

This code adds a menu in the Settings section of Wordpress' administrator

Right now `add_options_page` is declared, so the custom menu appears inside **Settings**

I changed **add_options_page** to **add_menu_page** in order to bring that menu to the top-level, but then it stopped working (when I click the custom menu opens, but can't save settings anymore).

What's the remaining code I have to change in order to make this work?

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php

add_action('admin_menu', 'create_theme_options_page');
add_action('admin_init', 'register_and_build_fields');

function create_theme_options_page() {
   add_options_page('Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'options_page_fn');
}

function register_and_build_fields() {
   register_setting('plugin_options', 'plugin_options', 'validate_setting');

   add_settings_section('main_section', 'Main Settings', 'section_cb', __FILE__);

   add_settings_field('color_scheme', 'Color Scheme:', 'color_scheme_setting', __FILE__, 'main_section');
   add_settings_field('logo', 'Logo:', 'logo_setting', __FILE__, 'main_section'); // LOGO
   add_settings_field('banner_heading', 'Banner Heading:', 'banner_heading_setting', __FILE__, 'main_section');
   add_settings_field('adverting_information', 'Advertising Info:', 'advertising_information_setting', __FILE__, 'main_section');

   add_settings_field('ad_one', 'Ad:', 'ad_setting_one', __FILE__, 'main_section'); // Ad1
   add_settings_field('ad_two', 'Second Ad:', 'ad_setting_two', __FILE__, 'main_section'); // Ad2
}

function options_page_fn() {
?>
<div id="theme-options-wrap" class="widefat">
<div class="icon32" id="icon-tools"></div>

<h2>My Theme Options</h2>
<p>Take control of your theme, by overriding the default settings with your own specific preferences.</p>

<form method="post" action="options.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php settings_fields('plugin_options'); ?>
<?php do_settings_sections(__FILE__); ?>
<p class="submit">
<input name="Submit" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save Changes'); ?>" />
</p>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}

// Banner Heading
function banner_heading_setting() {
   $options = get_option('plugin_options');
   echo "<input name='plugin_options[banner_heading]' type='text' value='{$options['banner_heading']}' />";
}

// Color Scheme
function color_scheme_setting() {
   $options = get_option('plugin_options');
   $items = array("White", "Black", "#DDDDDD", "#444444");

   echo "<select name='plugin_options[color_scheme]'>";
   foreach ($items as $item) {
      $selected = ( $options['color_scheme'] === $item ) ? 'selected = "selected"' : '';
      echo "<option value='$item' $selected>$item</option>";
   }
   echo "</select>";
}

// Advertising info
function advertising_information_setting() {
   $options = get_option('plugin_options');
   echo "<textarea name='plugin_options[advertising_information]' rows='10' cols='60' type='textarea'>{$options['advertising_information']}</textarea>";
}

// Ad one
function ad_setting_one() {
   echo '<input type="file" name="ad_one" />';
}

// Ad two
function ad_setting_two() {
   echo '<input type="file" name="ad_two" />';
}

// Logo
function logo_setting() {
   echo '<input type="file" name="logo" />';
}

function validate_setting($plugin_options) {
   $keys = array_keys($_FILES);
   $i = 0;

   foreach ($_FILES as $image) {
      // if a files was upload
      if ($image['size']) {
         // if it is an image
         if (preg_match('/(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/', $image['type'])) {
            $override = array('test_form' => false);
            $file = wp_handle_upload($image, $override);

            $plugin_options[$keys[$i]] = $file['url'];
         } else {
            $options = get_option('plugin_options');
            $plugin_options[$keys[$i]] = $options[$logo];
            wp_die('No image was uploaded.');
         }
      }

      // else, retain the image that's already on file.
      else {
         $options = get_option('plugin_options');
         $plugin_options[$keys[$i]] = $options[$keys[$i]];
      }
      $i++;
   }

   return $plugin_options;
}

function section_cb() {}

// Add stylesheet
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_register_head');

function admin_register_head() {
   $url = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/functions/options_page.css';
   echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='$url' />\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply a proper handle when registering the menu page(fourth parameter).

## Add menu example

Add top level menu page

```
add_menu_page( 'Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'manage_options', 'my-theme-options', 'options_page_fn' );
```

## Add submenu example

Add a submenu page to the new top level page

```
add_submenu_page( 'my-theme-options', 'Theme Sub1', 'Theme Sub1', 'manage_options', 'my-theme-options-subpage1', 'my_callback_function' );
```

Hope that helps..

And please consider posting your future WordPress questions on the [WordPress Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Regarding your main problem though, try updating the `do_settings_section` call to..

```
<?php do_settings_sections( 'main_section' ); ?>
```

Comment: @t31os I didn't know about WordPress Stack Exchange. Thanks!

Comment: It's still young, but steadily growing.. :)

Comment: @t31os I tried the code you described above and still not working (I replaced the add_options_page(... for your add_menu_page(... :(.

Comment: Do I have to change all the add_settings_section to something like add_menu_section?

Comment: Well that certainly threw me off, havn't used the `add_settings_section` and `add_settings_field` functions in a while(there's a shortcut you can use, but that's for another topic). Try this: http://wordpress.pastebin.com/bxE2vNrx

Comment: @t31os Thanks it works! The only thing now is that the "Settings saved." message doesn't appear (but the settings are saved).

Comment: So add a little code to see if the updated request is present.. `</php if( isset( $_GET['updated'] ) && ( 'true' == $_GET['updated'] ) ) : ?>Settings updated.<?php endif; ?>`, or similar.. The options.php page your form submits to sends these in the redirect after it saves(look at your page URL after saving settings)..

Comment: @t31os Thanks again, one more question: where should place the code above? (between html tags or inside a function?). By the way the URL after saving is: http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=home%2Falex%2Fwww%2Fwordpress%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Fstarkers%2Ffunctions%2Fadmin-menu.php&updated=true

Comment: `<?php if( isset( $_GET['updated'] ) && ( 'true' == $_GET['updated'] ) ) : ?><div class="updated">Settings saved.</div><?php endif; ?>` stick that after the heading(h2) in your settings page..